# Get details of a controller class dynamically

Tags: developer

I want to get all details of a controller class like for which objects class is working and for which fields of an object we are using in our class in both cases insertion or update and retrieving a records from an objects.

I want to do it dynamically, like I can or have to pass the class name as a string from a text box and get all details when I will click on a button.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are familiar with java programming language. Java has such instrument as reflection. Apex have reflection as well, but in very limited version. You can't invoke a method based on a string. It is not possible. You can only instantiate an interface/class based on its name. For more details see [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_type.htm).

Vote an idea at [success community](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrVaAAK) for reflection in Apex